# Matplotlib -- Outlining a irregularly shaped section of a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let me preface this by saying:  Don't worry about the grayscale heatmap.  That's not the topic of this question.

What I'm trying to do is this:  I have a heatmap, which indicates the flux values on a collection of pixels.  In my plot here, the pink pixels are included in the grouping, but no data is recorded for them.  The pixels that I have shown with a transparent-blue/green mask are the pixels that I would like to have outlined instead.  I want to draw a single outline around that entire group of pixels, like I've shown in the second pixel.

I used a masked array to get the blue overlay, but I can't figure out how to adapt that to an outline.  I need this to be able to work regardless of the shape of the grouping of identified pixels, as I will have tens of thousands of these plots to deal with.

In the masked array, the pink pixels have value 0, the pixels in the blue region are value 3, and all others are value 1.

What I was thinking (pseudo-code, because I don't know how to do this in code) is to have the script identify where a 3-pixel meets a 1-pixel, and for all cases where that is true, draw a line segment between the pixels.

I've included the following figures to demonstrate what I have VS what I'm wanting to do.  It doesn't matter what array of 0, 1, 3 values you use, as long as the 3's are all contiguous.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to tackle this?
[image: blue_overlay]
[image: blue_outline]

Comment: I would use binary morphology or the contour methods from scikit-image to find the edge pixels of the mask.

Comment: @tcaswell, could you elaborate on that a bit?  I have been programming for less than a year, and I decidedly don't speak the language!  :)  Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_contours.html for the contour implementation.  For the morphology, see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#module-skimage.morphology for implementations, theory wise ask google/wikipedia